# Using retina map tiles in d3/js with Stamen or CartoDB

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, retina-display

I am wondering how to modify my code to detect retina display and serve the enhanced tiles to users. I am typically using this code to call for tiles:

Stamen tiles:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
```

CartoDB tiles:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c", "d"][Math.random() * 4 | 0] + ".basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Adding @2x before the .png will give me high res with stamen, but not sure how to build the screen detector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it working by using:

```
function isRetina() {
return ((window.matchMedia && (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx), only screen and (min-resolution: 75.6dpcm)').matches || window.matchMedia('only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)').matches)) || (window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio > 2)) && /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);}

function isRetinaDisplay() {
if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), only screen  and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), only screen and (min-resolution: 1.3dppx)");
    if (mq && mq.matches || (window.devicePixelRatio > 1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;}
}
}

image.enter().append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    if (isRetinaDisplay) {
        return "http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + "@2x.png";
    } else {
        return "http://tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png";
    }
})
```

This is for the Stamen tiles. Basically just add the "@2x at the end of file name.